# How I can use HBase 2.0.4 version in Nifi?

Tags: hbase, apache-nifi

Nifi has HBase 1.1.2 client version. Can I use HBase 2.x version this HBase controller service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HBase 1.1.2 client against HBase 2.x server.

In the next NiFi release there will also be a an HBase 2 client service.

Comment: Thank you so much!